# ros distros and packages for kuka youbot

Tags: ros, kuka, ros-hydro, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the keyboard teleop app for the youbot, utilizing the hydro distro([www.youbot-store.com/youbot-developers/software/ros/ros-hydro-wrapper-for-kuka-youbot-api?c=24](http://www.youbot-store.com/youbot-developers/software/ros/ros-hydro-wrapper-for-kuka-youbot-api?c=24))

Now, the youbot oodl package is available in groovy. (wiiki.ros.org/youbot_oodl)

Moreover, the remastered ubuntu 12.04 comes with fuerte.

This is causing a lot of dependency issues. Any one who battled with this problem and came out with a way to handle them all?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164176/ros-distros-and-packages-for-kuka-youbot/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haylie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20690/haylie/) on 2014-12-01**:
I don't understand your question...you want to run the youbot in ros hydro but can't find the packages?
there is another github model for the youbot, maybe that is what you are looking for...
https://github.com/micpalmia/youbot_ros_tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install youbot_driver and its ros interface (on the youbot), using:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-youbot-driver
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-youbot-driver-ros-interface
```

Then, in order to run the keyboard program, first you need youbot_driver running, which will listen and execute the twist commands on the youbot:

```
roslaunch youbot_driver_ros_interface youbot_driver.launch
```

And then (in a new terminal) the keyboard tele-operation program, which publishes those commands:

```
rosrun youbot_driver_ros_interface youbot_keyboard_teleop.py
```

It will then print on screen what keys you should press.

---

Originally posted by [AlejandroBordallo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21077/alejandrobordallo/) with karma: 26 on 2014-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1